# External hard disk drive not detected on any computer

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, dmesg

My Adata HV 100 doesn't show up on computers; any computers. I am totally frustrated. It doesn't show up on Windows OS, Linux or Mac.

I ran most of the command I found but none of them worked. Here is the output for `dmesg` before I plugged in my HDD:

```
[27136.937677] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[27137.106486] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=125f, idProduct=a42a
[27137.106488] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[27137.106490] usb 1-2: Product: HV100
[27137.106491] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: ADATA
[27137.106492] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 4681241C3115
[27137.106867] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[27137.107524] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[27138.125899] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ADATA    HV100            9102 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[27138.126165] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[27138.127058] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[27139.149519] .
[27140.173609] .
[27141.197376] .
[27142.221304] .
[27149.389636] not responding...
[27329.381149] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[27509.378184] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[27648.266603] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[27648.281974] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[27648.281977] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[27648.281981] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[27648.281983] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[27648.282006] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
[27648.282008] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 30 f8 ec
[27648.282023] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[27648.282027] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[27648.282230] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[27648.282232] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[27648.282291] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

And after I plugged in my HDD:

```
Direct-Access     ADATA    HV100            9102 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[27138.126165] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[27138.127058] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[27139.149519] .[27148.364869] .
[27149.388800] .
[27149.389636] not responding...
[27329.381149] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180
[27648.266603] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[27648.281974] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[27648.281977] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[27648.281981] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[27648.281983] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[27648.282006] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
[27648.282008] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 30 f8 ec
[27648.282023] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[27648.282027] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[27648.282230] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[27648.282232] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[27648.282291] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[27796.373883] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[27796.554715] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=125f, idProduct=a42a
[27796.554718] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[27796.554719] usb 1-2: Product: HV100
[27796.554721] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: ADATA
[27796.554723] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 4681241C3115
[27796.555787] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[27796.555914] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[27797.574152] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ADATA    HV100            9102 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[27797.574416] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[27797.576055] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[27818.052724] .
[27897.920532] not responding...
[27909.919829] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[27909.919833] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[27909.919835] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[27909.919839] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[27909.919841] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[27911.919622] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[27913.919517] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[27913.919523] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[27913.923086] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[27914.943645] .
[279864004] .
[27986.587944] .
[27986.588779] not responding...
[28166.595194] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[28346.598318] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[28526.597690] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[28526.597709] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[28526.597711] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[28526.597714] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81
```

HDD does show up but stops at "**Spinning up disk**"

**OUTPUT FOR `lsblk` is:**

```
saroj@saroj-HP-Notebook:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1    7:1    0    82M  1 loop /snap/core/4327
loop8    7:8    0  81.7M  1 loop /snap/core/4206
loop6    7:6    0 192.2M  1 loop /snap/hiri/42
loop4    7:4    0  81.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4110
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop2    7:2    0 180.5M  1 loop /snap/vlc/190
loop0    7:0    0 125.6M  1 loop /snap/obs-studio/3
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda4   8:4    0 331.5G  0 part /media/Softwares
├─sda2   8:2    0   300G  0 part /media/Multimedia
├─sda3   8:3    0   100G  0 part /media/saroj/Documents 1GB
└─sda1   8:1    0 199.5G  0 part /
loop7    7:7    0  93.5M  1 loop /snap/slack/5
loop5    7:5    0 162.6M  1 loop /snap/spotify/6
loop3    7:3    0  93.5M  1 loop /snap/slack/6
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

Comment: `dmesg` shows that the device is being detect but the drive is not becoming ready (not responding) after spin up.  The hard drive is bad.

Comment: Can it be fixed?
and why does it say spinning disk before i even plugged in my drive?

Comment: I'd inspect the SMART data for the drive (`smartctl`), but really this is *not a Ubuntu issue* to me, but a hardware issue with a dead/dying drive.

Comment: @SarojGiri Those messages are from previous plug trial, system was still looking for the device.

Comment: Is it gonna work or not though?